# match records of a file with field values of another file in awk

Tags: bash, file, csv, scripting, awk

I want to sum up values in a field of a CSV file
where matching should be checked by reading another file,
say we have CSV_file:

```
adam,18
denis,19
julie,17
adam,15
max,20
julie,19
```

and a simple txt file containing:

```
adam
julie
```

all I need is to sum up 18,15,17,19
how could I easily do that with awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ s[$1]+= $2; next} {t+=s[$1]} END{ print t}' FS=, csv-file names.txt
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu, this gives `69`. What awk version and system are you on?

Comment: I figured out where this comes from, actually if I have a multi field csv file which I operate on only two of them, when I change $1 and two to corresponding column# in the file this does not work anymore What is the problem? ... awk 'NR==FNR{ s[$3]+= $5; next} {t+=s[$3]} END{ print t}'

Comment: @user3144923, is `names.txt` also multi column?  I think you want `awk 'NR==FNR{s[$3]+=$5;next}{t+=s[$1]}...'`, but it's hard to say without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `names.txt` is:

```
adam
julie
```

And `values.txt` is:

```
adam,18
denis,19
julie,17
adam,15
max,20
julie,19
```

Then you can make use of `grep`'s `-f` flag, which reads patterns from a file, one pattern per line, and returns all lines from `values.txt` that match any pattern. Then we just use `awk` to parse out the numbers and sum:

```
grep -f names.txt values.txt | \
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";total=0}{total+=$2}END{print total}'
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I divide total by a number in floating point arithmetic?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";total=0}{total+=$2}END{print total/<your denominator here>}'`, `awk` defaults to floating point arithmetic if the expression does not evaluate to an integer

Comment: unfortunately both total and denominator are integers... the division results floating point but I get it rounded to 0

Comment: what is the output you expect and what is the output you get

Comment: also id note that Ive answered the question as posed at this point, what we are talking about is a completely different topic (floating point arithmetic)

Comment: I think you never mentioned first column of CSV in your code. I expect to see a $1 somewhere in it. shouldn't I? because one could suppose there is a three or more column file and we want to check column 2 and sum column 3 values if matched